# Properly use Event Dispatch Thread in JApplet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, event-dispatch-thread

I've made a Java-based game that utilizes a JFrame containing a JApplet, which in turn contains a JPanel onto which the graphics are drawn, but for some reason, the left side of the graphics occasionally blinks, and I can't figure out why that is. I figure it may be because I've not actually used the EDT, something I only realized afterwards, so would someone be able to show me how I'd properly integrate use of the EDT into the program?

My main class looks like:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{

public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static RApplet app;

public Main(){
    setTitle("RCrawl");
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    final Player p = new Player(50, 70, true);
    final Room r = new Room(0xff222244);
    r.addEntity(new EntityRock(200, 150));
    app = new RApplet(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    app.setRoom(r);
    app.setPlayer(p);
    app.setFps(25);
    add(app);
    setVisible(true);
    new UpdateThread().start();
    System.out.println("thread run");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main m = new Main();
}

class UpdateThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        while(true)update();
    }

    public void update(){
        app.refresh();
    }
}
}
```

While the RApplet class looks like:

```
public class RApplet extends JApplet{
public int width, height, fps;
public long curTime, delta;
public RenderPanel panel;
public Room curRoom;
public Player player;
public boolean isSingle;
public InputHandler input;

public RApplet(int x, int y){
    width = x;
    height = y;
    panel = new RenderPanel(width, height);
    fps = 30;
    isSingle = true;
    input = new InputHandler();
    addKeyListener(input);
    setFocusable(true);
    add(panel);
}

public void setPlayer(Player p){
    player = p;
    curRoom.addPlayer(p);
}

public void setFps(int f){
    fps = f;
}

public void initialize(){
    curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    delta = curTime;
}

public void refresh(){
    delta = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() - curTime);
    if(delta > 1000 / fps){
        curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        render();
        tick();
    }
}

public void setRoom(Room r){
    curRoom = r;
}

public void render(){
    panel.renderStart(curRoom);
    panel.renderRoom(curRoom);
    panel.renderEnd();
    panel.repaint();
}

public void tick(){
    curRoom.tick(this);
}
}
```

So what would I want to do in order to use the EDT properly? I've tried a few things using different combinations of `invokeLater()` and `invokeAndWait()`, but couldn't get them to work. If you can help, any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the render method from the `RenderPanel`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    BufferedImage drawer = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g1 = drawer.getGraphics();
    g1.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, this);
    g2.drawImage(drawer, 0, 0, this);
    g1.dispose();
    g2.dispose();
}
```

Wouldn't that be double-buffering?

Comment: `"that utilizes a JFrame containing a JApplet"` -- why this *very* strange and fragile design? Shouldn't this be a JFrame that holds a JPanel?

Comment: I'm using the JFrame to test it before moving the Applet to a webpage.

Comment: 1. Don't do your BufferedImage drawing in the paintComponent method, i.e., everything from `BufferedImage drawer =....` to `g1.drawImage(...)`. That should be done elsewhere, possibly in a background thread. Also, while it's fine to dispose of the BufferedImage's Graphics object, g1, when you're done with it, never dispose of the Graphics object given to you by the JVM, namely the g2 object. This will break Swing's painting tree.

Comment: Don't call update, call repaint. Don't update the state of the model outside of the EDT, as painting might occur at anytime and you could end up with a race condition between the paint and update processes. Consider using a Swing Timer instead

Comment: Redesign your game, so all the logic is contained out side of the applet and frame, this allows these classes to act just as containers, allow the other classes to model the game state and render it

Answer (score 1):

## Issues...

- Be careful updating the state of the game from outside of the Event Dispatching Thread, this could lead to dirty paints as part of the state is update during the paint process
- Don't dispose of `Graphics` contexts you didn't create, disposing of system `Graphics` context will affect how other components are painted, remember, you might not be the only thing been painted during a paint cycle and the `Graphics` context is a shared resource
- Because of the way it's implemented, `repaint` is a thread safe method.  The paint event is posted on the Event Queue, which is processed by the Event Dispatching Thread, so unless you're doing something horribly wrong (printing been a possible exception to the rule), painting will always occur within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread
- There's no point rendering to a `BufferedImage` within `paintComponent`, Swing components are already double buffered.  If you want to implement page flipping, then you should be painting to more than one `BufferedImage`, but should be updating the off screen buffer outside of the EDT
- The basic structure of the code doesn't make sense, you give a lot of control to the `JApplet` AND `JFrame`, but neither should have any, they should be nothing more than containers for the `RenderPanel`

## Possible solutions...

Start by simplifying the rendering/updating process.  I'd consider using a Swing `Timer` as the main engine for the update process, it simple, it triggers it's updates within the EDT, meaning that it would be safe to make changes to the game state without worrying about race conditions and dirty painting.  It allows you to take advantage of the `paintComponent` method directly.

When you get the basic process running, you could explore more advance update engines (like using a `Thread`) and page flipping technquies

Change the structure of you program, separating the core program from the upper view requirements (`JApplet` and `JFrame` should be nothing more than containers for the actual program and contain only enough logic to construct and show the program)

[image: MVC]

Further separate the game logic into it's own class(s) which has no rendering logic.  Separate the controller from the rendering view as well.  The API would feed information to the controller (mouse events and key events for example), which would update the model.  The controller would also act as the main update engine, scheduling the update cycles in order to update the model and view as required.

See [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for more details.

Comment: Looks at this point like I might as well start from scratch then, huh?

Comment: At least a bit of cutting and pasting ;)

Answer (score 0):

Calling repaint will queue an event on the EDT. .

If you are experiencing flickering I would take a look at how long the render method actually takes to execute (and maybe render to a BufferedImage offscreen and have your paint method only draw that. ) , switch between the bufferedimage you are painting to and the buffered image that is drawing on the screen when rendering is completed. (this is known as double buffering.)

You could use BufferStrategy (p.s. im not 100% sure if that will work for applets or if it requires a full window. )

And this is all assuming that you are not doing anything silly such as grabbing hold of the graphics context being passed into the paint method and then using it in other methods (such are your render-room method) or calling "getGraphics()" on any components from those methods.

A lazy way of checking which thread you are in is printing out

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

or

```
Thread.dumpStack();
```

in methods where you directly access the graphics object.

Comment: I added the `paintComponent()` method, isn't it already using double buffering?